# how to disable only cut option on textview android

Tags: java, android, textview

I applied this code for Textview Selection

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

its working Great for selecting and copying Text. but there is a problem I don't want cut and paste option on texview in other words i want to make my textview only readonly so that it only give permission of copy not cut or edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is speculation, but it is somewhat informed speculation.

`TextView` defines two methods that are potentially useful here: `onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu)` and `onTextContextMenuItem(int id)`.

You could create a subclass of `TextView` and override `onCreateContextMenu()` to remove the cut option:

```
@Override
protected void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu();
    menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut);
}
```

Or you could create a subclass of `TextView` and override `onTextContextMenuItem()` to ignore the cut option:

```
@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    if (id == android.R.id.cut) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
}
```